# please help me understand the algorithm for building the KMP failure function

Tags: algorithms, strings, string-matching

I am struggling to grasp the algorithm for building the KMP failure function. The bulk of what is making my understanding incomplete concerns the line `length=PI[length-1]`. There is the psuedo code for the algorithm below. Here are my questions:

1.) How do we know that in the event `s[i] != s[length]`, the best possible option for our candidate prefix length is  `PI[length-1]`?

2.) If the candidate `PI[length-1]` fails, and on the next iteration of the while loop, we must go to `PI[PI[length-1]-1]` how do we know that the best possible candidate length is not actually BETWEEN `PI[length-1]` and `PI[PI[length-1]-1]`?

3.) When `s[i]!=s[length]` how do we know there does not exist a suffix(that matches a prefix) that ends at `s[i]` and that begins at a point in the string PRIOR to `i-length`?

I think my confusion could best be cleared by short informal proofs.

```
function f(string s): 

PI = an array of integers with size equal to length of s

length=0
i=1

while i < the length of the s:
    if s[length] == s[i]:
        length+=1
        PI[i]=length
        i+=1
    else:
        if length!=0:
            length=PI[length-1]
        else:
            PI[i]=0
            i+=1
return PI
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The failure link at a certain position $k$ in the string points to the longest prefix of the string which is also a suffix of the string *before* the position $k$.

The first observation we need is that in fact *all* the prefixes that are suffixes at that point can be found using repeatedly following the failure links. This implies that there are no positions in between.

So, if $k$ points to $t_0$ then the string indicated by $(0)$ in my diagram is the prefix/suffix at $k$. The next prefix that is also a suffix at $k$ is $t_1$ the failure link at $t_0$. The reason is that the two strings $(1)$ at the prefix match (by definition of failure link at $t_0$) but can also be found as $(1')$ at the end of the suffix.   Thus, any prefix/suffix at $t_0$ must also be a prefix/suffix at $k$.

[image: failure links]